# Audio files on front-end in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, rubygems

this is a best practices/performance question with regard to audio files in Ruby on Rails.
I am creating a Ruby on Rails application and I'd like to give users and easy way to click on certain strings of text in my application and hear an audio playback of that string (I am aware that there are other solutions to this like text-to-speech browser plugins, but I'd like to explore this option first).
I am familiar with the paperclip gem, I use it extensively in my application, and it has an easy to use interface for uploading the file with form helpers, storing it's url simply into a database column for a particular object, and ultimately referring back to the image url with an easy view helper.

Is there a gem similar to this for audio file uploading that anyone knows of?

And how hurtful towards the performance of my application would it be to add a few database columns which refers to the location of an audio file, to a few of my models?

How hurtful towards the performance of my app would it be to load somewhere between 3-10 short audio files (maybe 10 seconds long each), on each of my pages? I can store the audio files with AWS.

Thanks in advance for ANY help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're just creating a link to an audio file? You possibly need some js audio player library to do playback so it doesn't actually try to make you download the file. There's probably zero load for your server since everything is done on the browser side.

Comment: Okay thank you. I need to look more into this. I'll start looking at js players! Thanks!